# How to align text beside an icon?

Tags: html, css

I have a contact us page in which I have a picture followed by an icon and some text. I want to align the text beside the icon.

```html
<div class="col-lg-7 col-md-7 col-xs-7" style="text-align: center;">
       <img src='../assets/img/Website-Png/map2.jpg' >
       <br><br><br>
       <div>

           <i class="fa fa-map-marker" id="contact_icon1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           <span class="contact_font1">505-506, Kshitij Building, Veera Desai Rd, <br> Andheri West, Mumbai 40 0053</span>

       </div><br>
       <div>
           <span>
               <i class="fa fa-phone" id="contact_icon2" aria-hidden="true"></i>
           </span>
           <span class="contact_font2">+91 22 6470 1000</span>
       </div><br>
       <div>
           <span>
               <i class="fa fa-envelope-o" id="contact_icon3" aria-hidden="true"></i>
               <span class="contact_font3">info@mentoria.com</span>
           </span>
       </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: the icon is already beside the text. you can see here : https://jsfiddle.net/h3agfd6c/

Answer (score 0):

try this

add class to your div :

```
<div class="icon-text-group">
       <i class="fa fa-map-marker" id="contact_icon1" aria-hidden="true"></i>
       <span class="contact_font1">505-506, Kshitij Building, Veera Desai Rd, <br> Andheri West, Mumbai 40 0053</span>
</div>
```

then add css for the class :

```
.icon-text-group i, .icon-text-group span {
     display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use too much **divs** and though if you want to use div no need to use line break. As, div is block level element, it will automatically start on next line. You can use `<p></p>` instead.

also,

you can write text immediately after `<i></i>`

eg,

```
    <p>
      <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> 243 Elm Street,Claremont,NH 03743
      <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> <a href="#">603-542-7771</a>
    </p>
```

You can add contact number in anchor tag, and if you need you can add class to anchor tag.

Always try to wrap up your code in as less divs as possible. This will help to load your page faster.